# bind an object model to XtraReport devexpress

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, devexpress, reporting

I need to bind a xtrareport ( devexpress ) to an object model.

Suppose that my model is :

```
public class ReportViewModel
{
        public Header Header { get; set; }
        public Body Body { get; set; }
        public Footer Footer { get; set; }
}
```

I've already done the template report through the designer.

How should I do to feed the report from the view model with C# ?

This one doesn't work

```
XtraReport1 report = new XtraReport1();
report.DataSource = viewModel;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It's not enough just to set the DataSource of the report to your ViewModel, you will also need to bind the controls to the appropriate fields.  Here's how I've done something similar for a report in WinForms:

```
public IssueReport(DataTable issuesTable)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataSource = issuesTable;

    xrlabelIssueNumber.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.DataSource, "IssueID");
    xrlabelAssignedUser.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.DataSource, "Assigned User");
    xrlabelPriority.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.DataSource, "Priority");
    xrlabelCategory.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.DataSource, "IssueCategory");
    xrlabelReceivedDate.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.DataSource, "ReceivedDate");
    xrlabelDueDate.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.DataSource, "DueDate");
    xrlabelProduct.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.DataSource, "Product");
    xrlabelStatus.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.DataSource, "Status");
    xrlabelSubStatus.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.DataSource, "Sub-Status");
    xrlabelVersion.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.DataSource, "VersionNumber");
    xrlabelCustomer.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.DataSource, "CustomerName");
    xrlabelLocation.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.DataSource, "LocationName");
    xrlabelRoom.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.DataSource, "RoomName");
    xrlabelPOC.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.DataSource, "POC");
    xrlabelOfficeNumber.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.DataSource, "OfficePhone");
    xrlabelCallbackNumber.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.DataSource, "CallbackNumber");
    xrlabelEmail.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.DataSource, "Email");
    xrlabelAlternateEmail.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.DataSource, "AlternateEmail");
    xrlabelSummary.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.DataSource, "IssueSummary");
```

}

The `DataBindings.Add` method takes 3 arguments; 1st being the Property of the object in which you want to bind to (99% of the time it's the `Text` property of a XtraReportLabel). The 2nd is the BindingSource (in your case, your ViewModel...but this may need to be converted to a BindingList of some sort first).  The 3rd is the field of the BindingSource that you want to use.

Hope that helps....

Comment: additionally, to bind a object it have to be a list<yourObject> and have to put a bindingsource (windows form control) to the report https://documentation.devexpress.com/#xtrareports/CustomDocument7547

Comment: if you do that binding, when select the label can choose at design time the binded field or subproperty (see doc)

Answer (score 0):

You have to send list.

```
var viewModelList = new List<ReportViewModel>(){viewModel};
```